# I think I have three different versions of neovim installed, how do I use the npm installed one?

Tags: neovim, installing

I ran `npm install -g neovim` I get version neovim@4.9.0

If I run `nvim --version` I get v0.4.3

How do I use the npm installed neovim instance?

Comment: Well, where does npm install global programs? I imagine you’ll need to adjust your path for that (or just find the executable and invoke it directly)

Comment: I believe what you get with `npm install neovim` is simply the node.js module named neovim, not the editor itself... What's your O.S. and if Linux, what distribution/version? You mentioned three versions of NeoVim installed, what is the third one... Is anything not working as expected, or are you just trying to keep it clean with matching the versions?

Comment: I think I've actually got it sorted now. Installed with apt, and it should update with apt too.